# Search customer by lastname php and mysql (mvc pattern)

Tags: php, mysql

PHP & MySQL (MVC pattern)

Im currently working on a project. I've got a database with products, technicians, and customers tables. So far ive got functions to get data from the products and technicians table and then displayed them in a table. I got more functions to delete and add products and technicians. 
Now I need to create a page that lets you search a customer by their last name and the results are to be displayed in a table. Can anyone explain to me how to do this? I tried it with the mySQL 'like' but i can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: can you post your code that you ve tried and didnt work?

Comment: http://mikero.se/web182/tech_support/customer_manager/   I found the application online but the source code only displays the html which doesnt help much. I tried to create a function in a file called customer_db.php like this: function get_customers(); 
                                           global $db;
                                           $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers
                                                           WHERE lastName 
                                                            LIKE '%":last_name"$:' ';

Comment: And then in the html file i put name="last_name" in the input tag.
In the index.php file I set an action variable and used the post method to try and get the user input from the search field and then called the function from the customer_db.php file. It worked with adding and deleting technicians and products and displaying tables but it doesnt work with searching customers.

Comment: '<?php

function get_customers() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers
              WHERE lastName
              LIKE '%last_name%'';
              
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $customers = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $customers;
}'

Comment: <?php require'../view/header.php'; ?>

<div id='main'>
    <h1>Customer Search</h1>
    
    <form action="index.php" method="post"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search_field">
        
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type='input' name='last_name'>
        <input type='submit' value='Search'>
    </form>

Comment: <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>&bnsp;</th>
        </tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $result) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $result['firstName']; echo $result['lastName'] ; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['city']; ?></td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
            
</div>
<?php require'../view/footer.php'; ?>

Comment: <?php

require '../model/database.php';
require '../model/customer_db.php';

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action == NULL) {
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
    if ($action == NULL) {
    $action = 'search_field';
    }
}

if ($action == 'search_field') {
    $last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last_name');
    if ($last_name == NULL) {
       $last_name = 'A';
       $customers = get_customers();
    } else {
       $customers = get_customers();
        include('customer_search.php');
    }
    
} 

?>